# Django changing template_name in get_context_data dynamically

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates

how do I override the `template_name` of a `TemplateView` based on the context in `get_context_data`? In other words, I would like to find a way to change the template rendered according to my context.

The following is modified from my current code and it does not work:

```
class FooPage(TemplateView):
  template_name = "folder/template1.html"
  
  def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['myvariable'] = MyModel.objects.get(pk=kwargs['some_criterion']).variable
    if "text" in context['myvariable']:
      template_name = "folder/template2.html" # This line does get executed
    return context
```

I can confirm that the line changing `template_name` is executed and it is indeed set to `"folder/template2.html"` at that point, but the actual page that gets rendered still looks like the original (`template1.html`) instead.

Any helpful insight would be deeply appreciated. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write:

```
template_name = "folder/template2.html"
```

You are just declaring a local variable which will never get used. Instead you want to modify the *instance variable* which you can access / modify by accessing `self`:

```
class FooPage(TemplateView):
    template_name = "folder/template1.html"
    
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['myvariable'] = MyModel.objects.get(pk=kwargs['some_criterion']).variable
        if "text" in context['myvariable']:
            self.template_name = "folder/template2.html"
        return context
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! I have actually tried it before, but for some reason it tells me `self.template_name` is not defined. I tried it again just now and it worked perfectly. Thanks again!